# Color of pixel in ARSCNView

Tags: swift, uiimage, arkit, arscnview, sceneview

I am trying to get the color of a pixel at a CGPoint determined by the location of a touch. I have tried the following code but the color value is incorrect.

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if let touch = event?.allTouches?.first {
        let loc:CGPoint = touch.location(in: touch.view)
        // in debugger, the image is correct
        let image = sceneView.snapshot()
        guard let color = image[Int(loc.x), Int(loc.y)] else{
            return
        }
        print(color)

    }
}
....

extension UIImage {

subscript (x: Int, y: Int) -> [UInt8]? {
    if x < 0 || x > Int(size.width) || y < 0 || y > Int(size.height) {
        return nil
    }
    let provider = self.cgImage!.dataProvider
    let providerData = provider!.data
    let data = CFDataGetBytePtr(providerData)

    let numberOfComponents = 4
    let pixelData = ((Int(size.width) * y) + x) * numberOfComponents

    let r = data![pixelData]
    let g = data![pixelData + 1]
    let b = data![pixelData + 2]
    return [r, g, b]

}
}
```

Running this and touching a spot on the screen that is a very large consistent bright orange yields a wide range of RGB values and looking at the color they actually produce yields a completely different color (dark blue in the case of the orange).

I'm guessing that maybe the coordinate systems are different and I'm actually getting a different point on the image possibly?

EDIT: Also I should mention that the part I'm tapping on is a 3D model that is not affected by lighting so the color should and appears to be consistent through run time.

Answer (score 0):

Well it was easier than I thought. I first adjusted some things like making the touch be registered within my sceneview instead:

```
 let loc:CGPoint = touch.location(in: sceneView)
```

I then reproportioned my cgpoint to adjust to the image view by doing the following:

```
let image = sceneView.snapshot()
let x = image.size.width / sceneView.frame.size.width
let y = image.size.height / sceneView.frame.size.height
guard let color = image[Int(x * loc.x), Int(y * loc.y)] else{
   return
}
```

This allowed me to have consistent rgb values finally (not just numbers that changed on every touch even if I was on the same color). But the values were still off. For some reason my returned array was in reverse so I changed that with:

```
let b = data![pixelData]
let g = data![pixelData + 1]
let r = data![pixelData + 2]
```

I'm not sure why I had to do that last part, so any insight into that would be appreciated!